# React Native TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got the error while evaluating a const object, here's a minimal working example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}></View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:colors.bg,
  },
});

const colors = {
  bg:'blue',
}

export default App;
```

Error message: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'colors.bg')`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define **colors** const before the **styles**.

**Try This**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return <View style={styles.container}></View>;
};

const colors = {
  bg: 'blue',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.bg,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: This works, thank you.
Why `colors` has to be defined before `styles`, but `styles` can be defined after `App`?

Comment: In javascript code will be read line by line that's why in your code colors.bg is not define before calling it thats why its value is undefined. You can upvote if my answer is helpful. Thanks.